# The error appears when i try to use apply function to Google play store apps dataframe - ''int' object has no attribute 'endswith'"

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

I work with Google play store apps dataframe from [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps/tasks), and there is a problem on second task.
In the task, you need to define the application with the largest size. Problem in point that Series 'Size' has object type and also contains  sizes in megabytes (example: '20M'), kilobytes (example: '560k') and string 'Varies with device'

To solve this, i diceded to build a function and applied it to dataframe

```
def convert(x):
    """
    Function checks the end of the string in order to define memory scale.
    If it ends on "M" function returns only digits, convert them into the float type and round to 2 signs after dot. 
    If it ends on "k" function returns digits, divide them on 1024, convert them into the float type and round to 2 signs after dot.
    If it ends on "e" function returns zero. Condition for string "Varies with device".
    """
    if x['Size'].endswith('M'):
        return np.round(float(re.findall('\d+\.?\d', x['Size'])[0]), 2)
    elif x['Size'].endswith('k'):
        return np.round(float(re.findall('\d+\.?\d', x['Size'])[0]) / 1024, 2)
    elif x['Size'].endswith('e'):
        return np.round(0, 2)

apps['Size_conv'] = apps.apply(convert, axis=1)
```

After execute cell with apply func i got an error.
Strange thing that if i call dataframe again with

```
apps = pd.read_csv('googleplaystore.csv')
```

End execute cell with apply func again, error disappears.
How manage with this behavior? I can't call data frame again. Because it deletes my solves for another tasks.

**PS Before task number 2, i solved only the 1st task, where i dont use column 'Size'**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7lns.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch it to string, like this:

```
if x['Size'].str.endswith('M'):
```

Comment: it doesn't work( i added your variant to my func. and after executed cell with func it returned with an error

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Pls post a sample of your dataset

Comment: There is the link in the description on kaggle where u can find dataset "googleplaystore.csv"